# Colocação pronominal

Tags: pronomes, formalismo, colocação-pronominal

As regras de colocação pronominal no português formal são, eu diria, um tanto quanto complicadas. Existe alguma regra simples e/ou mnemônica que facilite a fixação de quando usar os três casos de colocação pronominal: **próclise**, **mesóclise** e **ênclise**?

Por exemplo, uma vez aprendi em um programa do professor *Pasquale Cipro Neto* uma regra simples sobre quando usar **mal** ou **mau** através da seguinte associação

> **mal** - **bem** (as letras *l* em mal e *e* em bem vem antes das letras *u* em mau e *o* em bom)
>
> **mau** - **bom**

Daí para sabermos se devemos usar **mal** ou **mau** basta trocarmos a ocorrência, na frase, por **bem** ou **bom**, e a partir do que fizer mais sentido recuperamos a frase através da relação anterior. Por exemplo:

> *Eu fui (**mal** ou **mau**?) no teste.*
>
> *Eu fui **bem** no teste.* Faz sentido
>
> *Eu fui **bom** no teste.* Não faz sentido

Logo, o correto é usar **mal**.

O que eu procuro é alguma regra simples assim que se aplique no caso de colocação pronominal.

Comment: Enquanto que talvez gramaticalmente corretas, as frases dos exemplos _soam_ erradas. Faria mais sentido _Eu **saí-me** bem_ ou _Eu **fiz** bem no teste._

Comment: *Eu fui bem no teste* e *Eu fui bom no teste* não faz muito sentido pelo menos em Portugal.

Comment: @JorgeB. no Brasil o *Eu fui bom no teste* causa estranheza ao contrário de *Eu fui bem no teste*...

Comment: @Larara uma coisa é estranhesa outra é ser correto. Neste caso não sei se será correto.

Comment: @JorgeB. _Fui bom no teste_ soa estranho em Portugal mas está gramaticalmente correto e faz sentido. Afinal nós dizemos em _sou bom na escola_, e uns anos depois dizemos _fui bom na escola_. Já _fui bem no teste_, só me parece gramaticalmente correto se _fui_ for interpretado como  o pretérito perfeito de _ir_ (_ser_ pede o adjetivo bom, não o advérbio bem), mas _ir bem no teste_, ainda que compreensível, soa-me bué estranho.

Comment: Mas de todas as sugestões, _saí-me bem no teste_ do @someonewithpc é a que soa mais natural em Portugal. _Fiz bem no teste_ parece-me errado. _Fazer é transitivo_: em Portugal perguntavam-te logo, _fizeste bem o quê?_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDITADO de acordo com comentários abaixo acerca das diferenças entre o português brasileiro e de Portugal (ou europeu).

---

## Português brasileiro

### Próclise primeiro

Via de regra, dê prioridade à próclise:

> Eu **te** avisei.
>
> Eu não **te** falei.
>
> **Te** avisei. (informal)

### Depois a ênclise

Use a ênclise quando o pronome for a primeira palavra da oração<sup>1</sup>:

> Avisei-**te**, mas em vão.
>
> Estavas errado, falei-**te**.

*<sup>1</sup>: No português brasileiro **formal**, é necessário usar a ênclise no início de orações.*

### Só então a mesóclise

Por fim, recorra à mesóclise **apenas** quando você precisar usar a ênclise em verbos conjugados nos tempos futuros (futuro do presente e futuro do pretérito):

> Avisar-**te**-ei, quando necessário.
>
> Falar-**te**-ia que estavas errado, mas não me deixaste.

---

## Português europeu

### Ênclise primeiro

Via de regra, dê prioridade à ênclise:

> Eu avisei-**te**.
>
> Falei-**te** daquilo.

### Depois a próclise

Caso haja uma negação na oração, deve-se utilizar a próclise:

> Eu não **te** avisei.
>
> Não **te** falei daquilo.

### Só então a mesóclise

Por fim, recorra à mesóclise **apenas** quando você precisar usar a ênclise em verbos conjugados no futuro do presente e no condicional:

> Avisar-**te**-ei, quando necessário.
>
> Falar-**te**-ia que estavas errado, mas não me deixaste.

---

*Obs.: Coloquei o português brasileiro em primeiro lugar apenas porque me parece que a pergunta está mais próxima dessa variante.*

[Fonte](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coloca%C3%A7%C3%A3o_pronominal)

Comment: No português de Portugal (não sei porque usam "Europeu" se é só de Portugal) não usamos o *"Eu te avisei"*.

Comment: @JorgeB. Usa-se apenas "avisei-te"?

Comment: Usa-se "Eu avisei-te".

Comment: @JorgeB. Bom ponto. Se dizem "português europeu", por que não dizem "português americano"? Por outro lado, "português de Portugal" parece mais trabalhoso de dizer. E "português português" soa bastante redundante.

Comment: É mais trabalhoso mas é o mais correto, português europeu dá ideia que existem mais países na Europa a falar português.

Comment: @JorgeB. Pergunta: não seria "eu avisei-te" apenas porque o verbo avisar se inicia por vogal, que entraria em conflito com o "e fraco" do pronome "te" do português de Portugal? Se o verbo fosse "falar", o português de Portugal ainda privilegiaria a ênclise?

Comment: Se fosse falar dependeria de como dizes as coisas. "Eu falei-te" ou "Eu não te falei". Agora fiquei na dúvida, foi bem colocada essa questão.

Comment: @JorgeB. Em "eu não te falei", a negação exige a próclise. "Eu não falei-te" não é possível em nenhuma variação do português. De qualquer maneira, me parece que há uma predileção pela ênclise no português de Portugal. Devo editar a resposta para refletir essa diferença entre as variantes?

Comment: Ah não sabia. Mas o mais comum é mesmo usar o "-te". Não sei, se achares que deves edita.

Comment: * de Portugal ;)

Comment: @BellAppLab, em Portugal diz-se _eu avise-te_, mas (praticamente) qualquer outra palavrinha que se meta naquela frase exige a próclise: _eu não te avisei, eu já te avisei, eu até te avisei, quando é que eu te avisei? eu ainda te avisei_, etc. etc. etc. Nas frase seguintes quer a próclise quer a ênclise me soam bem, mas não tenho a certeza do que diz a gramática: _eu dei-me ao trabalho de te avisar, eu fiz tudo para te avisar, foi por eu te avisar que tu soubeste._  É irrelevante se o verbo começa por vogal ou consoante.

Comment: @Jacinto Vou atualizar a resposta. Mas, a fim de criar uma regra simples, como foi pedido, tenho duas perguntas. 1) Como ficaria a colocação pronominal na seguinte frase: "meu trabalho é te avisar"?; 2) Nos exemplos que você deu, como ficaria a colocação pronominal caso suprimíssemos o "eu"?

Comment: Em Portugal diz-se "o meu trabalho é avisar-te", e os meus exemplos ficam na mesma se tirares o _eu_. Curiosamente a maneira como os portugueses falam obedece, com raras exceções, às regras definidas neste site brasileiro [link](http://www.infoescola.com/portugues/colocacao-pronominal-proclise-mesoclise-enclise/).

Answer (score 3):

Eu consegui da nossa complicação destilar uma regra relativamente simples. Mas só garanto a sua validade em frases com verbo simples; não se aplica tempos compostos ou locuções verbais como *tenho dito, vou dizer, quero dizer*; e mesmo assim há de certeza muitas exceções. Foi o que eu consegui arranjar.

Nota prévia: a mesóclise é um mero substituto da ênclise no caso do futuro do presente (*ver-te-ei*) e do futuro do pretérito/condicional (*ver-te-ia*).

Regra simples: a ênclise e mesóclise usam-se **apenas** em frases “básicas”; em todos os outros casos é obrigatória a próclise. Frase “básica” é a que começa com sujeito ou verbo; se tiver alguma palavra antes, ela está separada do sujeito ou verbo por pausa, como em (c):

> (a) Eu ligo-**te** amanhã; eu ligar-**te**-ei amanhã.
>   (b) Ligo-**te** amanhã.
>   (c) Amanhã, ligo-**te**.

Se houver antes do sujeito ou verbo uma palavrinha qualquer diretamente ligada a eles, então só se usa a próclise:

> (d) **Já te** ligo; **já te** ligarei.
>   (e) Eu **não te** liguei.
>   (f) **Amanhã te** ligo.

Agora, em Portugal é só isto. No Brasil, este uso da ênclise e mesóclise é considerado correto e pode ser até preferido na linguagem formal. Mas na linguagem coloquial é comum a próclise mesmo nas frases básicas. Começar a frase com o pronome átono (*Te ligo amanhã*), só mesmo no registo coloquial.

Mais exemplos de frases “não básicas”:

> (g) **Nunca te** liguei.
>   (h) Eu **mesmo te** ligo.
>   (i) Eu **até te** liguei! Estás tu a dizer **que eu me** esqueci do teu aniversário!
>   (j) **Por me** lembrar é **que te** liguei.
>   (k) Eu **sempre me** lembrei; tu é **que te** esqueces sempre.
>   (l) Eu **só te** liguei (não fui bater à tua porta).
>   (m) **Só eu te** liguei; mais ninguém.
>   (n) **Se te** liguei, foi por engano e já **me** esqueci.
>   (o) Queres **que te** ligue?
>   (p) **Quando te** liguei, não atendeste.
>   (q) Toma, **para te** lembrares de mim.
>   (r) Estou **onde nos** conhecemos.
>   (s) **Que bicho te** mordeu?
>   (t) A possibilidade **de eles te** ligarem é remota.
>   (u) **Talvez te** ligue.
>   (v) **Caso te** liguem, atende.

E pronto regra simples é esta. Agora, há exceções. Por exemplo, alguns sujeitos pedem a próclise mesmo em frase “básicas”:

> (w) **Ninguém/alguém me** ligou.
>   (x) **Todos me** ligaram.
>   (y) **Nada te** acontecerá.
>   (z) **Algo me** diz que há mais exceções.