# Colocação pronominal em Portugal

Tags: português-europeu, colocação-pronominal, informalidade, formalismo

No Brasil, é comum estudar regras de colocação pronominal, aliás nimiamente detalhadas,[¹](https://resumosparaconcursos.com.br/2018/02/09/colocacao-pronominal/) na preparação para exames de ingresso às universidades e concursos públicos, que, de modo geral, são diferentes do modo como falamos e não soam naturais a nossos ouvidos. Ensina-se que devemos usar essas regras ao escrever na norma culta da língua, mas, como todos acostumados com o português brasileiro sabem, não aplicamos tais regras à nossa fala.

Não é difícil notar que portugueses seguem essas regras, mesmo em contextos informais. Para pessoas que tem o português europeu como língua materna, essas regras são completamente naturais? Os portugueses nunca erram a colocação pronominal ou devem estudar regras similares na escola?

¹ [Resumos para concursos (Colocação pronominal)](https://resumosparaconcursos.com.br/2018/02/09/colocacao-pronominal/)

Comment: Poderás estar interessado em ver [esta pergunta sobre colocação pronominal](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/294/coloca%c3%a7%c3%a3o-pronominal).

Comment: E obrigaste-me a ir ver *nímio* ao dicionário!

Comment: Boubarki, substituí o endereço de internet pela descrição do link (o link funciona); a reformatação do "1" da nota de rodapé foi só porque não consegui deixar aquilo com os parênteses como tu tinhas (entrava em conflito com os parênteses do código). Podes reverter ao que tinhas ou alterar à tua vontade (clica em "edit").

Comment: Sem problemas, Jacinto, creio que tenha ficado melhor assim. E obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Sempre às ordens, Bourbaki. Pergunta interessante, +1. O meu primeiro pensamento foi, não, há uma única norma de colocação pronominal usada em todos os registos, mas afinal encontrei uma exceção, que é mais generalizada do que eu pensei ao princípio; acrescentei uma nota sobre isso.

Comment: @Rye, [nímio](https://dicionario.priberam.org/n%C3%ADmio) não é um erro tipográfico. Reverti a tua edição.

Comment: Sou brasileiro. Eu sempre achei que as regras de colocação pronominal tivessem sido inventadas para não haver confusão dentre palavras; porque, para mim, pareciam arbitrariíssimas e complexas de mais para se terem desenvolvido naturalmente. Acho legal ver que não é o caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal como o Jacinto, não me recordo de as regras de colocação dos pronomes clíticos serem formalmente ensinadas na escola. Recordo-me, por exemplo, de aprender as formas aglutinadas *mo*, *no-lo*, etc.. Mas não creio que o facto de serem ensinadas na escola tenha muita influência na forma como as pessoas falam; em particular não me lembra alguma vez ter ouvido um *no-lo* ou *vo-lo*.

Quão de perto os portugueses seguem as regras depende muito da região e meio social em que cresceram. Contrariamente ao português do Brasil, os desvios ocorrem na direção da ênclise. [Apesar de algumas opiniões em contrário](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/controversias/a-colocacao-dos-pronomes-cliticos-ou-a-proliferacao-dos-erros-induzidos/3313), a maioria dos gramáticos defendem que a ênclise é o padrão de colocação básico no português europeu (desde meados do séc. XVIII). A gramática de Maria Mateus e outras defende esta posição (pág. 850 da 6.a ed.):

> [A]s primeiras produções com pronomes clíticos das crianças portuguesas exibem generalizadamente o padrão enclítico, contrariamente ao que está descrito para outras línguas românicas.
>
> (8) a. não chama-*se* nada (M., 20 meses)
> b. é que não estragou-*se* (J. G., 39 meses)
> c. porque é que foste-*me* interromper? (R., 29 meses)
> d. foi alguém que meteu-*me* nesta fotografia? (J. G., 39 meses)
> e. mas ele já foi-*se* embora (P, 39 meses)
> f. que(ro) pôr os papeles aqui pa(ra) não rasgar-*se* (P., 39 meses)
>
> Por outro lado, e de uma forma consistente com os dados de aquisição exemplificados em (8), as gerações mais novas tendem a produzir crescentemente clíticos enclíticos, em contextos em que a variedade padrão exige próclise, como se pode observar em (9):
>
> (9) a. porque não apercebeu-*se* que... (12 anos, modo escrito)
> b. correspondem à classe onde "só" combina-*se* com SN (estudante universitário, modo escrito)
> c. Todos os verbos volitivos e optativos fazem-*se* anteceder sempre de um SN. (estudante universitário, modo escrito)
> d. Também sabe-*se* que existe uma certa altura da criança... (estudante universitário, modo escrito).
>
> [...] [D]ados como os apresentados em (9) mostram que a ênclise é o padrão de colocação em expansão [na variedade europeia].

A minha experiência em Lisboa é que a generalidade das pessoas seguem quase sempre as regras de colocação conforme descritas nas gramáticas (com muita variação em relação aos verbos com que fazem subir o clítico e quanto ao padrão a usar em frases infinitas com certas preposições como *para*), mas que é comum entre pessoas que cresceram nalguns subúrbios mais pobres usar a ênclise em situações proibidas na língua padrão. A não ser que sejam casos subtis, é um erro estigmatizado (veja-se, por exemplo, quando o presidente do Benfica usou *O que passou-se?*). E conheço ainda um caso mais extremo, de uma madeirense que usa a ênclise mesmo em muitas frases na negativa.

Answer (score 2):

Saí recentemente do secundário e lembro-me apenas de aprender algures na primária/básico as formas corretas de proceder à colocação pronominal, quando estávamos a aprender a conjugar verbos, e de falar dos contextos que exigem alguma atenção. Por exemplo, no caso do verbo *ter-se*:

- no modo condicional/futuro do indicativo: colocar pronome entre radical e terminação do tempo verbal (ter-me-ia, ter-te-ia, ter-se-ia, tê-lo-ei, ter-vos-ei...)
- nos casos de negação/subordinação/interrogação: utilizar o pronome anteposto

  Deve-se ter cuidado. Não se deve ter cuidado. É aconselhável que se tenha cuidado. Será que se deve ter cuidado?

Claro que quando se cometem erros de colocação, os professores de português corrigem os alunos.

Mas a socialização trata disto. Toda a gente à nossa volta fala mais ou menos da mesma forma (respeitando estas regras de colocação pronominal), pelo que isto acaba por ser *mais* natural.

Answer (score 1):

Tão naturais como beber um copo de água (ok, talvez com uma exceção). Eu nunca aprendi regras de colocação pronominal na escola. Aliás quase não aprendi gramática. A disciplina de língua portuguesa incidia sobretudo sobre literatura. Não sei se as coisas mudaram entretanto.

Eu vi aqui há uns tempos sites brasileiros sobre colocação pronominal, motivado por [esta pergunta sobre o assunto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/294/coloca%C3%A7%C3%A3o-pronominal) que cá apareceu, e fiquei surpreendido ao ver que eles basicamente descreviam a maneira como os portugueses falam. Não garanto que não haja diferenças entre o prescrito nesses sites e a maneira como nós falamos. Mas aqui em Portugal não existe uma colocação pronominal culta por oposição a uma coloquial, ao contrário por exemplo do *eu gostava de ir, mas não posso* coloquial, que num registo mais formal poderá ser substituído por *eu gostaria*... Colocação pronominal, há só uma para todos os registos.

Erro, erro, possivelmente só em coisas do tipo, *eu faria-te companhia se tivesse tempo* em vez do *eu far-te-ia*. Não se armasse em culto e dissesse *eu fazia-te*... que já não se enganava. Mas a substituição pelo pretérito imperfeito já não é possível (sem alteração de significado) em coisas como *ele estar-lhe-ia a mentir?* e também aqui não é incomum, *ele estaria-lhe a mentir?* Depois, ainda relacionado com colocação pronominal, ouvem-se coisas como *fazem-o, faze-o* e *querze-o*, por oposição ao padrão *fazem-no, fá-lo* e *quere-lo*.

Comment: As coisas mudaram entretanto, mas não imenso. Definitivamente, quem não sabe falar direito, não é nas aulas de português que vai mudar... :)