# "Já te livraste dessa" ou "Já livrastes-te dessa" qual a forma correta?

Tags: verbos, significado-em-contexto, concordância, formalismo

"Já te livraste dessa" ou "Já livrastes-te dessa" qual a forma correta?

Comment: CiMend, dizes *livrastete*, com o verbo *livraster*(?), ou *livraste-te*? Se disseres *livraste-te*, então, o correto é «já te livraste dessa»., pois, *já* é advérbio.

Comment: No Brasil, se coloca antes; em Portugal, depois. Não entendo porque você não coloca o International Keyboard no seu computador.

Comment: "livrastes" é segunda pessoal do plural. tome apenas cuidado com isso

Comment: CIMent, em PT-PT para mim, só a primeira "Já te livraste dessa" estaria correcta.

Comment: @JJoao Consegues fundamentar a resposta e colocar aqui na área da resposta?

Comment: @ClMend, fundamentar em língua natural é algo escorregadio... Vou tentar descrever...

Comment: http://alfclul.clul.ul.pt/wochwel/documents/Cl%C3%ADticos_Gram%C3%A1tica%20do%20Portugu%C3%AAs_Gulbenkian.pdf secção 65.1.3.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em ptpt, para mim, só "Já te livraste dessa" estaria correcta, mas é muito frequente no calor da conversa ignorar as regras gramaticais.

Normalmente a língua mãe aprende-se de ouvido, daí a pouca preocupação em enunciar as regras --> o ideal é consultar uma gramática, ou
algo como google(conjugação pronominal).

Resumidamente algumas anarco-regras ptpt (inventadas à pressa) para conjugação verbal com pronome (complemento indirecto pronominal):

1. em orações subordinadas -> proclise

   - "ele disse que **te despachasses**"
2. em orações com negativas -> proclise

   - "nunca **te levantas** cedo"; não **te levantes** tarde!
3. após (alguns) advérbios -> proclise (sem vírgulas)

   - "(já|ainda|...) **te safaste** dessa"
4. em orações principais e nas suas orações coordenadas (e, mas, ...)-> Ênclise

   - "**Safei-me** desta";
   - "**levanta-te** da cama e **penteia-te**"
5. imperativo (não negado) -> ênclise

   - "**levanta-te** da cama!"

- ...
  PF: ajudem-me a completar as regras

Comment: Para as regras em geral já existe [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/294/coloca%c3%a7%c3%a3o-pronominal).