# “te avisarei” vs “avisar-te-ei”

Tags: significado, gramática, português-europeu, colocação-pronominal

What's the difference between:

- (1) te avisarei
- (2) avisar-te-ei
- (3) avisarei-te (if this is even correct?)

Are they interchangable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Avisarei-te* is nonstandard; otherwise, all three mean the same. The choice between *avisar-te-ei* and *te avisarei* has to do with syntax and the presence of adverbs. For instance, in a simple main clause I would say:

> Fica descansado, **eu avisar-te-ei** quando ele chegar

but in a subordinate clause (all in boldface),

> Fica descansado, eu já disse **que te avisarei** quando ele chegar

This is so in European Portuguese and (very?) formal Brazilian Portuguese. In colloquial Brazilian Portuguese, the pronoun comes before the verb nearly all the time. See [this question](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/294/coloca%C3%A7%C3%A3o-pronominal) about the placement of these pronouns.

The distribution between *avisar-te-ei* and *te avisarei* is the same as between *aviso-te* and *te aviso*. The reason we have the pronoun in the middle of the verb rather than at the end is that the -*ei* is a remnant of the auxiliary verb *haver* (same with *ia* in *avisar-te-ia*); so a long time ago the *te* would be at the end of the main verb (*avisar-te hei*) just as in *aviso-te*.

In practice, you won’t hear *avisar-te-ei* that much (or *te avisarei*, for that matter), because we tend to replace the simple future with the present or *ir* + infinitive. Say, rather than the examples above, I would much more likely say:

> Fica descansado, **eu aviso-te** quando ele chegar
> Fica descansado, eu já disse **que te aviso** quando ele chegar

Comment: How is `avisar-te-ei ` pronounced? As 3 distinct words? Or do "te-ei" get merged into a single world similar to "teei"?

Comment: @Nicholas, it is pronounced as a single word. You can listen to [amar-te-ei here](https://forvo.com/word/amar-te-ei/#pt), same sound.

Comment: I'd bet that in written Iberian Portuguese, yes, but spoken? Not often, right?

Comment: @Lambie, right, not common at all. I'd hoped I had addressed that point, at the end... or are you talking of something else?

Comment: No, I'm talking about that. Maybe you should loose the "beast"?  mesóclise? :)

Comment: just as a complement, in Brazilian portugues the "avisar-te-ei" form virtually doesn't exist, you will only see it being used by a judge in the court or by some politicians that, for some reason that I do not know, want to look overly inteligent

Comment: @FabricioG Hey, don't diss my technical texts and reports! I use "constituir-se-ão" and similar phrases as often as I should, since it is the only grammatically correct form available.